# Node.JS downloading hundreds of files simultaneously

Tags: node.js, express, youtube-dl

I am trying to download more that 100 files at the same time. But when I execute the downloading function my macbook freezes(unable to execute new tasks) in windows also no download(but doesn't freeze) and no download progress in both case(idle network).

Here is my download module:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
var links = require('../models/Links');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    links.find({dlStatus: false}, function (err, docs) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.end();
        } else if (!docs) {
            console.log('No incomplete downloads!');
            res.end();
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {

                //todo scraping


                var video = youtubedl(docs[i].url, [], {cwd: __dirname});

                // Will be called when the download starts.
                video.on('info', function (info) {
                    console.log('Download started');
                    console.log(info);
                });

                video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/' + docs[i].id + '-' + i + '.mp4'));
                video.on('complete', function complete(info) {
                    links.findOneAndUpdate({url: info.webpage_url}, {dlStatus: true}, function (err, doc) {
                        if (err)console.log(err);
                        else console.log('Download completed!')
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now can anyone please help me here? I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl) module for downloading files.

Comment: Is downloading working for single..?

Comment: yes, i tried with 5 downloads simultaneously, that worked too, now I am trying with 101 , then this happenes

Comment: Try it using async.That will work

Comment: `async.each()` ..in this case because you have to iterate over array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is using **async** in this case.

Try it this way....with `async.each()`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
var links = require('../models/Links');
var async = require('async')

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    links.find({dlStatus: false}, function (err, docs) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.end();
        } else if (!docs) {
            console.log('No incomplete downloads!');
            res.end();
        } else {
            async.each(docs,function(doc,cb){
              var video = youtubedl(doc.url, [], {cwd: __dirname});

              // Will be called when the download starts.
              video.on('info', function (info) {
                  console.log('Download started');
                  console.log(info);
              });

              video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/' + docs.id + '-' + i + '.mp4'));
              video.on('complete', function complete(info) {
                  links.findOneAndUpdate({url: info.webpage_url}, {dlStatus: true}, function (err, doc) {
                      if (err){
                        console.log(err);
                        cb(err);
                      }
                      else {
                        console.log('Download completed!');
                        cb()
                      }
                  });
              });

            },function(err){
              if(err)
                return console.log(err);
              console.log("Every thing is done,Here!!");
            })
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And you can process every thing in batch too using `async.eachLimits()`.

Comment: thanks , i just forgot to handle error. Both our codes working fine :)